# Accessing the name of a list by defining a new class, error: NamedList instance has no attribute '__len__'

Tags: python, list, class, ironpython

I am pretty new to python, 
So I have created a list of elements like:

```
main_list = [1,2,3]
```

I want this list to have a name and I don't want to use a dictionary, so I have created a class with the name as an attribute:

```
class NamedList:
     def __init__(self, name, obj)
          self.name = name
          self.object = obj
```

when I try to access the length of the first list:

```
len(main_list)   #works fine
```

but for the second one it gives me this

> error: NamedList instance has no attribute '**len**' :

```
new_main_list = NamedList('numbers', main_list)
len(new_main_list)      #This line gives me the error
```

I wanted to know why the basic attributes of the List class are not available for my class? all my instances are originally a List instance.

Thanks in advance

Comment: implement a [`__len__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__len__#object.__len__) method for your `NamedList` class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a subclass of `list` and it will inherit all of the list methods, including `.__len__()`.

```
class NamedList(list):
    def __init__(self, name, iterable):
        super().__init__(iterable)
        self.name = name
```

> all the instances are list instances originally, so why methods of the list class do not work for them and why I have to define a subclass?

*Having* a list attribute is not the same as *being* a list. Think about what `len()` is supposed to do if you have multiple list attributes, or no lists. You weren't exposing the required interface. The `len()` builtin works by calling `.__len__()` on the object, but your original class didn't have that method. Instead it has `.object.__len__()`, in other words, it has a list object and *that* has the required method. `len(new_main_list)` doesn't work, but `len(new_main_list.object)` would have.

The subclass, on the other hand, *inherits* the attributes of its parent class (`list`). If an attribute lookup on `NamedList` fails, it will try looking it up on `list`, which has `.__len__()`, so it works.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this method was the best way I guess. it worked perfectly. Just out of curiosity, why I have to define a subclass? cause as I said all the instances are list instances originally, so why methods of the list class do not work for them and why I have to define a subclass?

Answer (score 4):

Add `__len__` method to your class like,

```
def __len__(self):
    return len(self.obj) # or return self.obj.__len__()
```