# 'MyList' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, class, oop

Dears,
I am trying to understand better the OOP paradigm in Python, so I've created this simple class

```
class MyList:
    def __init__(self,list):
        self.list=list

list1=MyList([1,2,3,4,5])
```

Until here is everything fine, the problem occurs when I try to set a value to any element of my list. As example:

```
list1[0]=5
```

Then I got this TypeError: 'MyList' object does not support item assignment

Someone could help me with this?

Comment: `list1.list[0]=5` You have to access the `list` attribute since `list1` is not a `list`, its a `MyList` instance.

Comment: You may want to implement some "magic methods" like [`__getitem__` and `__setitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__).

Comment: See [Emulating container types](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing the name of a list by defining a new class, error: NamedList instance has no attribute '\_\_len\_\_'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60427254/accessing-the-name-of-a-list-by-defining-a-new-class-error-namedlist-instance)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\_\_setitem\_\_ implementation in Python for Point(x,y) class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774804/setitem-implementation-in-python-for-pointx-y-class)

Comment: Why do you expect ``MyList`` to support item assignment? The code shown does not define any such operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're trying to better understand OOP, here's something you can try: Subclass `list` itself, so your class gets all the properties that `list`s do.

```py
class MyList(list):
    def __init__(self,list):
        super().__init__(list)

list1 = MyList([1,2,3,4,5])
list1[0] = 5

print(list1)
# [5, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have any code in the class that allows for item assignment. For an object to allow item assignment, it needs to implement [`__setitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__).

You would need something like:

```
class MyList:
    def __init__(self,list):
        self.list=list

    def __setitem__(self, i, elem):
        self.list[i] = elem
```

Comment: Hi Carcigenicate, thanks for your support. I already tried this but I get this same error message...

Comment: @blhsing I did, but for some reason I had lookups in my head while I was writing the second half. I'm not sure why. Fixed.

Comment: @ViniciusMiki I had the wrong method. I wrote it while listening to a lecture and evidently my brain got distracted. Try the corrected code.

Answer (score 1):

```py
class MyList:
    def __init__(self,list):
        self.list=list
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.__dict__)

list1=MyList([1,2,3,4,5])
print(list1)

list1.list[0]=5
print(list1)
```

You need to assign to the list attribute not to the class

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to create a new MyList type which should have the functionalities of a normal Python list plus some functionalities you might like to add or modify. For this to work, you need to inherit from the inbuilt Python `list` class, like so,

```py
class MyList(list):
    pass

list1=MyList([1,2,3,4,5])

list1[0]=5
```

Now in your `MyList` class, define only those methods which you want to change in the inbuilt `list` class

Answer (score 0):

I got it!
I implemented the special method setitem and getitem and it worked. Thank you all

```
class MyList:
    def __init__(self,list):
        self.list=list

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.list[index]
    
    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        self.list[index] = value
```